# How to load image in asynchronous manner on hover effect in React.js?

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

You might have seen this type of effect. Example - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GEmOQy

But I need to implement same way in React. I know I can use `componentDidMount` method for ajax, but thing is how to display response on hover.

I don't had practice on implementing hover with react, like I do in pure css approach with `:hover`.

So any solutions are welcome.

Comment: use `componentDidMount` for AJAX. See https://daveceddia.com/where-fetch-data-componentwillmount-vs-componentdidmount/

Comment: Yes right correction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This a very flat question, and there are many possibilities. All I can give is a basic skeleton on how to do it.
Define a `ImageCard` component in whose `componentDidMount` you do the API call. Then on your parent component ( whichevere component the button is ), store a `state` key that manages whether to show the card or not:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      showCard: false
    };
  }
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        {
          this.state.showCard &&
        <ImageCard/>
        }
        <button
          onMouseEnter={() => this.setState({ showCard: true })}
          onMouseLeave={() => this.setState({ showCard: false })}
          >Hover Me!</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: I'll try this one.

Answer (score 0):

Use `onMouseEnter` event on the button and load a new image when it fires,

```
class SomeComp extends Component{
   coonstructor(){
      this.state = {
          url: 'http://some-intial-url.com'
      }
      this.onMouseEnter = this.onMouseEnter.bind(this)
   }
   onMouseEnter(){
       this.setState({
          url: GetOtherImageURl()
       })
   }
   render(){
      <img src = {this.state.url} />
   }
}
```